# Browser blocks cross domain iframe cookies

Tags: django, cookies, iframe, django-allauth

I have a forum-like component which I use in an iframe on other websites. This component uses django-allauth for authentication with Facebook and Twitter. Everything worked fine but now the authentication stopped working some time ago. When I look at the cookies in my browser, the cookies from Facebook/Twitter which are set by the iframe, are not loaded. Although, the cookies from the component itself are set.
The authentication still works when I load the iframe on a website which is on another subdomain of the component itself.

Tool on another subdomain (working):
https://shop-sandbox.adbuddy.be/discussie/

Tool on a totally different domain (not working):
https://mama-calinka.webbuddy.be/discussie/

I guess this problem had something to do with CORS-headers but nothing I've tried helped. Can someone help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this stopped working only very recently, it could be related to the Chrome's recent [breaking change](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592) , that in case cookie's attribute SameSite is not explicitely set it defaults to SameSite = Lax, which prevents your browser in cross site requests to sent the cookie over.

I checked your https://shop-sandbox.adbuddy.be/discussie/  - there are many cookies with SameSite empty.

There could be a couple of more reasons, why a browser ignores a cookie in the request and I tried to sum all of them in my blog [here](https://medium.com/swlh/7-keys-to-the-mystery-of-a-missing-cookie-fdf22b012f09)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was indeed the problem. For other Django users, you have to update your Django version to at lease 3.1 and in your settings.py file set `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'` `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'` `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True`